# Overfitting in Machine Learning and mathematical background of it

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, mathematical-statistics, error, overfitting

Simply we know that when we train a model if validation error stops improving i.e. if it started to increase we called it "overfitting". If there is a high variance with low bias we can expect it. But what is the mathematics under that?

Comment: its essentially a heuristic.  We initialise the weights around zero (check exactly initialisation for relus), where a model has low variance. The number of training steps influences how large the weights can become and have higher variance.

Answer (score 1):

For intuition, one can think of overfitting in the context of solving a system of equations with measured data points. As shown in the plot, suppose you have four measurements, three of which ($x_1, x_2, x_3$) are the correct measurements and locate on a straight line, but fourth one was measured when you were watching a movie.

[image]

If you are only allowed to use straight line to fit those data points, you'll always end up with certain errors. That means you cannot solve the following equations for $w_0$ and $w_1$.

$$
w_0 + w_1x_1 = y_1\\
w_0 + w_1x_2 = y_2\\
w_0 + w_1x_3 = y_3\\
w_0 + w_1x_4 = y_4
$$

If you are not limited to choose the degree of polynomials, then you can increase your **modeling capacity** by add more higher degrees ($y=\sum w_ix^i$) to find a curve going through those four points exactly. That means you'll have zero training error but end up with a model with poor generalizability.

In terms of variance and bias, for models with high capacity, the prediction would have more space to jump around if the modeling procedure is repeated with adding more data.

The intuition is more heuristic than rigorous reasoning